# My application is considered an unknown app

Tags: android, apk, signed-apk

I developed an application in android studio and signed it, but when I try to install that I have this alert message

[image]

that says `your phone and personal data are more vulnerable to attack by unknown apps...`

why when I sign the app get this alert?

I must tell you that I live in Iran, may it be subject to sanctions?

I changed the package manager and the sign allot of but doesn't work 
and tried to put it on this site 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals

but it keeps telling me **cant download your app**
can anybody help me?

> Edited 
>   My problem solved that's error to happen because i install my apk from my SD card to my phone when i exam that to another phone by Bluetooth and so on thats ok hope it's helpful for others

Comment: how did you sign it and how did you install the app?

Comment: @gratient asimbahwe i sign that by the Build menu and then Generate and sign Bundle or apk    after make key and other .... create in release mode and install that apk in my phone   sorry for my bad English language

Comment: did you install the apk manually or you used android studio? what are permissions requested for the app?

Comment: Install that manually , copy that apk by usb cubl to my phone and then install that.
permissions are just phone state and network and permission.C2D_MESSAGE

Comment: one time commented all pernission and rebuild and make apk but still have that alert

Comment: I think some apps can be considered unknown app for begining, after some users download app it should be ok - I am not sure about it, I remember some situation like this on stackoverflow over 1 year ago I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved that's error to happen because i install my apk from my SD card to my phone when i exam that to another phone by Bluetooth and so on thats ok 
hope it's helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install Debug-APK its normal to see is as unknown app and ask you for permission, however if you are getting the same message with Release-APK than please check this out ["Unknown Source" in release apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158048/unknown-source-in-release-apk)

Comment: hi my friend that alert in release mode but that i I did not catch
 Relationship between my question and that link you send. can you tell some description

Comment: Do you have Proguard  enabled in your gradle ?

Comment: link screenshot of your gradle please

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISVdv.jpg


 https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOft0.jpg