# Configure proguard to exclude library jar which extends android.content.Context

Tags: java, android, proguard

I'm integrating a library into a device for a project which is going to be embedded into the device OS. For this, we're integrating a library jar which overrides the Android framework Context.

Because of this, trying to enable Proguard for the app gives me the following error - "there were 220 instances of library classes depending on program classes".

All of these files are Widgets and Views. How can I fix this?

This is the content of my proguard-project.txt

```
-injars      bin/classes
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars /Users/me/android-sdk-mac_86/platforms/android-15/android.jar
-libraryjars libs/library-that-overrides-context.jar

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.content.Context
```

This is the content of my proguard-android.txt

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

Comment: Is that a crash ? then post the complete stacktrace which will make more seance

Comment: Nope, these are warnings. If I use -dontwarn, the apk is formed, but I install it on the device, I can't get the logs...

Comment: Never mind.. I got the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542631/android-obfuscate-app-using-proguard-keeps-obfuscating-library-jars-or-is-it?rq=1

Comment: For future reference, I had to add the line -keep class `android.content.** { *; }` to my proguard-project.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I'd marked my library as a libraryjar, I also had to add the lines

`-keep public class android.content.** { *; }` to the project proguard config file to fix the issues.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Ant/Eclipse builds automatically specify all necessary -injars/-outjars/-libraryjars options for you. You should only specify these options if you have a custom build process. Otherwise, you'll get lots of warnings about duplicate classes and possibly other problems.

If you do need to specify -injars/-outjars/-libraryjars options, classes specified with -injars can depend on classes specified with -libraryjars, but not the other way around. Cfr. ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: library class ... depends on program class ...](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)

Comment: Yeah, I know this. But my project is not a normal Android application, as I stated. It has a library which overrides the system context and due to this, it was causing issues. I had to fix it by specifying --`keep class android.content.** { *; }` in my project specific proguard file