# Proguard warnings "can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry)"

Tags: android, warnings, proguard, android-support-library

I'm using IntelliJ and running Proguard in debug mode but I can't seem to get rid of warnings such as:

```
ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] 
(Duplicate zip entry [android-support-v13.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
```

This project has a couple of modules and `android-support-v13.jar` is being used on 2 of them. I thought that was the issue so I removed that library from the libs folder, added it as a project library and added the dependency to both modules. That didn't solve anything, the warning persists and I don't understand why.

I know these warnings don't affect anything but a clean build is a happy build!

Comment: Looks like `android-support-v13.jar` is being included more than once.  Also see [Warning: can't write resource ... Duplicate zip entry](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicatezipentry).

Comment: I don't understand how is that happening. Like I said, I added the library as a project library and referenced it on both modules. I need to do this otherwise the app won't compile.

Comment: Possibly a 'proguard.cfg' problem. Could you post it? It seems that some -injars included in it can be treated twice.

Comment: Try deleting the c:/ProgramFiles/User/.gradle folder

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Possibly a 'proguard.cfg' problem. Does it include any '-injars'? If your project includes another project as a library, jars can be processed twice. Could you post your 'proguard.cfg'?

Extract from http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/troubleshooting.html:

> Your input jars contain multiple resource files with the same name.
>   ProGuard continues copying the resource files as usual, skipping any
>   files with previously used names. Once more, the warning may be an
>   indication of some problem though, so it's advisable to remove the
>   duplicates. A convenient way to do so is by specifying filters on the
>   input jars. There is no option to switch off these warnings.

**OPTION #1:**

As you can't post your '-injars', check if they include either 'android-support-v13.jar' or the library included in your project which itself also includes 'android-support-v13.jar'.

**Assuming you are building with Ant inside IntelliJ IDEA, you mustn't add -injars, -outjars, or -libraryjars options; the Ant script already does that for you.**

**OPTION #2:**

Although the warnings are harmless, a clean build is a happy build, so try:

http://web.archive.org/web/20160206204259/http://www.dancartoon.com/2012/01/14/fixing-proguard-warning-cant-write-resource-meta-infmanifest-mf/

and

https://gist.github.com/paulpv/4439012

**OPTION #3:**

Include `(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)` after each '-injars' command

```
-injars library.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
```

**OPTION #4:** [Android Proguard Duplicate Definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805704/android-proguard-duplicate-definition)

> Fixed this by moving the 3rd party libraries to another directory, in
>   my case 'lib'. Then added
>
> ```
> -injars lib/jmdns.jar
> ```
>
> to the proguard.cfg file.

**OPTION #5:** [Android - Proguard duplicate zip entry error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279213/android-proguard-duplicate-zip-entry-error)

If your Proguard config file includes the following line, remove it:

```
-injars bin/classes
```

**OPTION #6:** [Android obfuscate app using proguard keeps obfuscating library jars - or is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542631/android-obfuscate-app-using-proguard-keeps-obfuscating-library-jars-or-is-it)

> I found another way to make Proguard leave library jars alone was to
>   ask it to preserve their package names, eg:
>
> -keep class javax.** { *; }
>   -keep class org.** { *; }
>   -keep class twitter4j.** { *; }

**OPTION #7:**

A weird solution (deleting META-INF folder in src folder) to something similar [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-994).

Comment: Yes, it does include a section with `-injars`. I can't post the file, it contains sensitive data that I cannot reveal.

Comment: The android-support-v13.jar was just an example, all other libraries inside the libs folder of the main module also generated that warning.

Comment: Try removing those libs from the -injars

Comment: Well, I updated my answer with alternative solutions. It's difficult without your config file nor your complete error log.

Comment: I can't seem to get rid of this, probably because there's something messed up on this project configuration. I'll just have to leave it like this for now. But since you provided such a detailed answer with lots of possible solutions, I'll mark the answer as accepted. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Thanks to you and sorry it didn't finally help.

Comment: is there igonre these jars ? coz i have the same issue , but cannot solve it

Comment: i didn't have a proguard.cfg file in my project, but still this error is there.

Comment: Do you know where dancartoon's post went, I get 404 :'(

Comment: This is by far the best answer I have seen in years. I am getting it but since it is harmless, I will take the option of doing nothing.

Answer (score 5):

I used `packagingOptions` with `exclude` in `build.gradle`, and I have same issues with you.

You can fix it using this.

```
packagingOptions { 
    pickFirst 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    pickFirst 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    pickFirst 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    pickFirst 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

Replace `pickFirst` with `exclude`.

Comment: Either with `pickFirst` or `exclude` the warning is still output when running a release build. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @JJD it still outputs the warnings.

Comment: pickFirst does not prevent the warnings from happening.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was to copy the -obfuscate target from /tools/ant/build.xml into your project's custom_rules.xml. Then the only block that needs to be changed is:

```
<pathconvert property="project.all.classes.value" refid="project.all.classes.path">
    <firstmatchmapper>
         <regexpmapper from='^([^ ]*)( .*)$$' to='"\1\2"(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)'/>
         <identitymapper/>
    </firstmatchmapper>
</pathconvert>
```

The only added bit is `(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)`. This will exclude all the manifest files, which won't be copied in to the final APK anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reference the support library by including its jar directly; when you do this, the build system can't disambiguate between multiple versions of it, and you get errors of this type. Include it by referencing its Maven coordinates:

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:X.X.X'
}
where X.X.X is the proper version number based on what API you're compiling against. If you include this dependency via the UI at Project Structure > (your module) > Dependencies > + Button > Library dependency it will help you choose the right version number.

You may also find it convenient to include other dependencies via Maven coordinates instead of wrangling their jars; that same library dependency UI has a search function to help you find libraries.

**be sure to remove this library from the libs or any other folder it was present inside**

Answer (score -5):

add `-dontwarn` to *proguard.cfg* to ignore warnings

Comment: This isn't a good option because you are simply ignoring all warnings no matter what. Some of them may actually help you!