# (Duplicate zip entry [coolLib.jar:{pkg}/BuildConfig.class]))

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-proguard

I have an android project in **Android Studio 2.3.0 beta4** which is dependent on a library project **CoolLib**.

**CoolLib** has its source in a jar file **coolLib.jar** in its *libs* folder. **coolLib.jar** contains file **{pkg}/BuildConfig.class**.

When i try to build and run the project in a device/emulator at Android API-22+, it runs perfectly but when i try to do the same on a device/emulator at API VERSION < 22, Android Studio **fails** to build with an Exception--

> Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\AndroidStudioProjects\CoolProject\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\debug\jars\3\1f\main.jar] (Can't read [D:\AndroidStudioProjects\CoolProject\CoolLib\build\intermediates\bundles\default\libs\coolLib.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [coolLib.jar:{pkg}/BuildConfig.class]))
>   :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug FAILED

The build.gradle of project contains the following versions of support lib etc.--

```
ext {
supportLibVer = '25.1.1'
playServiceVer = '10.0.1'

buildToolsVer = "25.0.2"

compileSdkVer = 25
targetSdkVer = 25
minSdkVer = 16
}


dependencies {
compile files('libs/FLurry_3.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/jxl-2.6.12.jar')

compile project(':CoolLib')

compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$playServiceVer"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVer"
compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVer"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibVer"
compile "com.android.support:support-v13:$supportLibVer"
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

Comment: Its says Duplicate zip entry [coolLib.jar:{pkg}/BuildConfig.class] post your full grade file

Comment: which part of the file you want me to show.

Comment: app:gradle mostly dependencies

Comment: @Charuක i've updated question with dependency part.

Comment: Use support libraries of the same version can you try compile "com.android.support:support-v13:$supportLibVer" --> to > `"com.android.support:support-v7:$supportLibVer"`

Comment: does `CoolLib` project depend on support library?Did you include the support library in the CoolLib?

Comment: @Charuක CoolLib is not dependent on any lib.. and you should know v13 is not v7 support lib.

Comment: check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357959/proguard-warnings-cant-write-resource-meta-inf-manifest-mf-duplicate-zip-en) also cleaning project can help.

Comment: @EliasFazel tried cleaning, invalidate cache and restart multiple time but no luck... and that link didn't make it work either.

Comment: please post your log cat..! It will be helpful

Comment: @shobhit LogCat fires at "runtime" ..i've posted the gradle console output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got the solution.

**The Why-**

I compared the build steps in gradle console at API22(build OK) and API16(build fails). At API22, the console said-

> +Instant Run: Proguard is not compatible with instant run. It has been disabled for debug
>
> +Instant Run: Resource shrinker automatically disabled for debug

..and the build was successful. When i disabled InstantRun, it failed on API22 also.

**The Reason-**

The problem was in proguard configuration. The **BuildConfig.class** of **coolLib.jar** was defined to be kept in **proguard-project.txt** , so it was keeping all the **.class** files in that package but **BuildConfig.class** must be modified at build time according to the Main Project.

**The Solution-**

I removed that **-keep** statement and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

The fix for me, was to put `packageBuildConfig = false` in the `android { ... }` section of the build.gradle files for the library project:

```
android {
    packageBuildConfig = false
    ...
}
```

Even if it's been depreceated it's still working.