# xamarin proguard can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, apk, proguard

I'm having troubles to use `Proguard` in `Xamarin`. Firstly, i had an error 1 with `Proguard`, but i fixed it by using a custom `proguard` configuration.

```
-dontwarn com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.**
-keep class com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.**
-dontwarn  android.support.multidex.**
-keep class  android.support.multidex.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.**
```

When i cleaned, and `builded` my solution, i'm having those errors:

```
can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [bolts-tasks.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [zxing.core.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [android-support-multidex.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
```

Despite those errors, my build finished. But when i compared my apk files, with or without Proguard, the sizes are the same! (It's like Proguard was not working...)

I tried many solutions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357959/proguard-warnings-cant-write-resource-meta-inf-manifest-mf-duplicate-zip-en) but none of them worked...

Also I updated proguard with a newer version, and the facebook fork, but it does not worked.

How can i fix that?

Comment: Add your custom proguard conf to your question

Comment: Hi, i just edited with my proguard config. waht do you think?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: No sorry, i'm still waiting for help on this.