# Dropbox sync api not working when using Proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am implementing the Dropbox Sync API in my Android app, Wallpaper Saver. It works when i run it in debug mode from eclipse, but when i export it and run it through proguard it throws this the following exception:

```
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.a.a(Unknown Source)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.ad.a(Unknown Source)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.ad.a(Unknown Source)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at dk.alroe.apps.WallpaperSaver.ADropboxConnector.a(Unknown Source)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at dk.alroe.apps.WallpaperSaver.ADropboxConnector.onCreate(Unknown Source)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.<init>(Unknown Source)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    ... 20 more
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='<init>' signature='(Lcom/dropbox/sync/android/NativeEnv;)V' in class Lcom/dropbox/sync/android/NativeHttp;
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeHttp.nativeClassInit(Native Method)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeHttp.nativeClassInit(Native Method)
08-25 23:09:52.833: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeHttp.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

As far as I understand, Proguard has removed a bit too much. How to stop Proguard from eating methods in the Dropbox jar?

Comment: Have you tried any of the methods described in [this answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6542704)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding following line to my proguard file solved the problem

```
    -keep class com.dropbox.** {*;}
```

Thanks to A--C for pointing me in the right direction!